Failed to get responsetext from sp_OAGetProperty
I have a project that need to hit a HTTP POST method using SQL Server. After I explored and asked chatGPT, I got a solution using Ole Automation procedures.
After I try I got the HTTP status correctly, but still failed to get response text.
Here is the stored procedure I created:
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_Http_Post_Request
    @Url NVARCHAR(500),
    @PostData NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Username NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @Password NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @ResponseText NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Object INT,
            @Source NVARCHAR(255),
            @Error NVarchar(255),
            @Description NVARCHAR(255),
            --@ResponseText NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @Status INT;

    -- Create an XMLHTTP object
    EXEC @Status = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
    IF @Status <> 0
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Failed to create OLE object', 16, 1);
        RETURN;
    END

    -- Open the connection to the URL
    EXEC @Status = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @Url, false;
    IF @Status <> 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object;
        RAISERROR('Failed to open URL', 16, 1);
        RETURN;
    END

    -- Set the request headers
    EXEC @Status = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/json';

    IF @Status <> 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object;
        RAISERROR('Failed to set request header', 16, 1);
        RETURN;
    END

    IF (ISNULL(@Username, '') != '' AND ISNULL(@Password, '') != '')
    BEGIN
        DECLARE 
            @Base64String NVARCHAR(1000),
            @AuthHeader NVARCHAR(1000);

            DECLARE @BinaryData VARBINARY(1000);

        -- Convert the input to VARBINARY
        SET @BinaryData = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Username + ':' + @Password));

        -- Encode the binary data to Base64
        SET @Base64String = CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@BinaryData"))', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)');

        -- Create the authorization header
        SET @AuthHeader = 'Basic ' + @Base64String;

        EXEC @Status = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', @AuthHeader;

        IF @Status <> 0
        BEGIN
            EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object, @Source OUT, @Description OUT;
            EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object;
            SET @Error = 'Failed to set Authorization header : ' + CHAR(10) +
                            'source : '  + @Source +  CHAR(10) +
                            'Description : '  + @Description
            RAISERROR(@Error, 16, 1);
            RETURN;
        END
    END

    -- Send the POST data
    EXEC @Status = sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', NULL, @PostData;

    IF @Status <> 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object, @Source OUT, @Description OUT;
        EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object;
        SET @Error = 'Failed to send data : ' + CHAR(10) +
                        'source : '  + @Source +  CHAR(10) +
                        'Description : '  + @Description
        RAISERROR(@Error, 16, 1);
        RETURN;
    END
    
    DECLARE @HttpStatus as int = 0

    EXEC @Status = sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'status', @HttpStatus OUT;

    IF @HttpStatus <> 200
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object, @Source OUT, @Description OUT;
        EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object;

        SET @Error = 'HTTP request failed with status code : ' + convert(nvarchar(10), @HttpStatus) + CHAR(10) +
                        'source : '  + @Source +  CHAR(10) +
                        'Description : '  + @Description
        RAISERROR(@Error, 16, 1);
        RETURN;
    END

    SELECT @HttpStatus AS Response;

    --Get the response text
    EXEC @Status = sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUT;

    PRINT @ResponseText
    PRINT @Status

    IF @Status <> 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object, @Source OUT, @Description OUT;
        EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object;

        SET @Error = 'Failed to get response text : ' + CHAR(10) +
                        'source : '  + @Source +  CHAR(10) +
                        'Description : '  + @Description
        RAISERROR(@Error, 16, 1);
        RETURN;
    END
    
    -- Clean up
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @Object;

    SELECT @ResponseText AS Response;
END;

I got this error after I execute the stored procedure.
Here is my execution code:
DECLARE @ApiUrl varchar(500) =  '';
DECLARE @Response NVARCHAR(MAX);

IF (@ApiUrl NOT LIKE '%/')
BEGIN
    SET @ApiUrl = @ApiUrl + '/'
END

SET @ApiUrl ='https://2ec45385-58f4-4842-a393-91d1810d0956.mock.pstmn.io/api/callback'

EXEC dbo.usp_Http_Post_Request
        @Url = @ApiUrl, 
        @PostData = '',
        @Username = '',
        @Password = '',
        @ResponseText = @Response OUTPUT;

PRINT @Response;

The error I got :

Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.usp_Http_Post_Request, Line 113 [Batch Start Line 0]
Failed to get response text :
source : ODSOLE Extended Procedure
Description : Error in srv_paramset.

The response should be
{
    "response_id": "aaa",
    "message": "Body cannot be empty"
    "remarks": []
}

Am I missing something? I would be glad for any help.

Seriously, why would you want to do this in SQL server? It's the last place you should be doiythis sort of thing.

Aside... you really shouldn't be using sp_OA methods if you like your SQL Server instance to have any semblance of stability and reliability - they leak memory and resources like a sieve. These sorts of things should be happening in external processes or, in a pinch, SQL CLR methods.

If you absolutely must keep using sp_OA methods then... the sp_OA methods predate the (max) data types that were introduced with SQL Server 2005, therefore sp_OAGetProperty cannot deal with varbinary/varchar/nvarchar(max) output parameters. If you cannot fit the response in varbinary(8000), varchar(8000) or nvarchar(4000) fixed length data types then you should skip the output parameter altogether and instead insert the data into a temp table or table variable.

I can't see any reason why anyone would "need" to keep using said ancient features in new work. If this were an old process then it would be a point to change the process, if it's new work then the objects should never have been even considered. Use middleware for this, written C#, python, powershell, what ever you want; SQL (Server) is the entirely wrong place though.

If true, this is probably also a great example of why CrapGPT isn't helpful; it should have told you it was a terrible idea using these tools, but it didn't (because it's not clever, it's just vomiting crap).

@ThomA perhaps the next iteration will stop recommending it, after stackoverflow data was sold to OpenAI, it has time to read up on the subject. Or it will self-destruct since so many bad advices seem to come from itself

"that need to hit a HTTP POST method using SQL Server" does it? Why not use Powershell for example, this is about one line of code Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://2ec45385-58f4-4842-a393-91d1810d0956.mock.pstmn.io/api/callback" -Header @{"Content-Type": "application/json"} -Method Post And if you really really need to do it from SQL Server, why not SQLCLR?
